# Can I restore my HP array after 2 disks replacement?

Tags: hp, raid5, data-recovery

I have HP array with 12 disk each on 2 TB. I configured them with RAID5
Suddenly two disk has ben failed and after two days another disk have been failed.
And the array failed to start.
I replaced the two failed disks.
The array configuration utility show me option to "re-enable the array"...
My question is if I choose that option, will I recover my data?
Or is it lost?

Comment: Restore from backup

Answer (score 3):

RAID5 only provides one disk fault tolerance. Replacing *two* disks of a RAID5 array effectively means **losing all stored data**.

So, short of contacting professional recovery services, your data are gone.

More broadly speaking, *never* use RAID5 for wide arrays and/or large HDDs.

Comment: Thanks, Can a professional recovery services restore my data?

Comment: That depends on the damage and can only be answer by said recovery services. Note that RAID increases uptime but doesn't replace a reliable backup.